# Org Mode - HTML Export Table Of Contents Without H2

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Looking for way to export a document with table of contents anchor links only (without the H2 that says "Table of Contents").

Basically would like to change from this:

**Table of Contents**

- Heading
- Heading
- Heading

To this:

- Heading
- Heading
- Heading

In the final export.

Comment: It looks like the function `org-html-toc` in `ox-html.el` always adds a "Table of Contents" string to the output. It uses `(org-html--translate "Table of Contents" info)`, so you could invent a fake language, say `en-no-toc`, so the translation of "Table of Contents" is the empty string. That would erase the text but leave an empty heading in the HTML. If you don't like that, you can redefine this function to omit it. Or you could use CSS to hide the heading (hide the element with `id="table-of-contents"` and override this in the child with `id="text-table-of-contents", so it shows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following lisp code introduces the new export keyword `TOC_NO_HEADING`. If it has the value `t` or `yes` the heading of the table of contents is surpressed.

```el
(require 'ox-html)

;; Adding keyword TOC_NO_HEADING to html export keywords:
(push '(:html-toc-no-heading "TOC_NO_HEADING" nil nil t) (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'html)))

(defun my-org-html-toc-no-heading (args)
  "Avoid toc heading in html export if the keyword TOC_HO_HEADING is t or yes.
Works as a :filter-args advice for `org-html-toc' with argument list ARGS."
  (let* ((depth (nth 0 args))
     (info (nth 1 args))
     (scope (nth 2 args)))
    (when (and (assoc-string (plist-get info :html-toc-no-heading) '(t yes) t)
           (null scope))
      (setq scope (plist-get info :parse-tree)))
    (list depth info scope)))

(advice-add 'org-html-toc :filter-args #'my-org-html-toc-no-heading)
```

Test:

- `emacs-version` 26.1
- `org-version` 9.1.13
- Test file:

```
#+TOC_NO_HEADING: t
* Test header 1
** Test header 1.1
Some text below test header 1.1.
** Test header 1.2
Some text below test header 1.2.
* Header 2
Some text below header 2.
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't read the source code of `org-html-toc` very carefully and didn't notice that when the `scope` parameter is non-nil you don't get the heading. This is much better than the approaches I outlined in my comment to the question.